# I need to read 100000 lines of a txt file and add each line into a array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a TXT file which contains 100000 lines of short strings from 1-3 digits long. I need a for loop that loops 100000 times, and in the loop I need to read a line then add it to an array and finally move down to the next line. The txt file is called Rand_Numbers and I have opened it as...

```
C_txt = open("Rand_Numbers", "r")
```

I don't really know how to do much in python as i'm fairly new to the programming scene. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list) is the same as yours.

Comment: `with open('ur_file.txt') as f: list_of_ints=[int(e) for e in f]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Python. how about

```
dump_here = []
with open('your_file.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        dump_here.append(line)
```

Comment: Ah yes this has done it thank you

Comment: You don't need `my_file.close()` that's the whole point of the context manager. Also, you can just do `dump_here = list(my_file)`